# php - class property not returning value

Tags: php, oop

I am wondering my class property `$friend_username` does not returning its value either it is public.

**update**

```
class Feed {
    public static $friend_username;

    // ONLINE FRIENDS LOGIC
    public function online_friends(){
        $friendsHTML = '';
        $countOnlineFriends = '';
        if(GetFriends($GLOBALS['log_username']) != false) {
            $all_friends = GetFriends($GLOBALS['log_username']);
            $orLogic = '';
            foreach($all_friends as $key => $user){
                if(IsBlocked($GLOBALS['log_username'],$user,true) == false){
                    $orLogic .= "username='$user' OR ";
                }
            }
            $orLogic = chop($orLogic, "OR ");
            $sql = "SELECT username, avatar, logged_in FROM users WHERE ($orLogic) AND logged_in = 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conx'], $sql);
            $friend_loggedIn = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $this->friend_username = $row["username"];
                $friend_avatar = $row["avatar"];
                $friend_loggedIn[] = $row["logged_in"];
                $friend_pic =  userImage($this->friend_username,$friend_avatar,'42','42',$link = false,$up = true);
                $friendsHTML .= '<li><a href="#" onClick="chatbox(\''.$this->friend_username.'\',\''.getName($this->friend_username,true).'\');return false;">'.$friend_pic.' '.getName($this->friend_username,true).'</li>';
                $countFriends = count($friend_loggedIn);
                $countOnlineFriends = ($countFriends > 0) ? '<span class="online_friends animated">'.$countFriends.'</span>' : '';
            }
        }else{
            $friendsHTML = 'No friends';
        }
        return "$countOnlineFriends|$friendsHTML";
    }

    public function update_chat() {
        $id = '';
        $messages = '';
        $randUser = '';
        $user = sanitize($this->friend_username);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_chat WHERE (sender='$GLOBALS[log_username]' AND receiver='$user') OR (sender='$user' AND receiver='$GLOBALS[log_username]') ORDER BY datetime DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conx'],$sql) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['db_conx']));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user1 = $row['sender'];
            $user2 = $row['receiver'];
            $message = parseData($row['message']);
            $did_read = $row['did_read'];
            $datetime = $row['datetime'];
            if ($user1 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $randUser = $user1;
            }elseif ($user2 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $randUser = $user2;
            }
            if ($user1 == $GLOBALS['log_username'] && $user2 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $messages .= '<li class="row" id="pm_row_'.$id.'"><div class="me">'.$message.'</div></li>';
            }else{
                $messages .= '<li class="row" id="pm_row_'.$id.'">'.userImage($randUser,getAvatar($randUser),28,28,$link = true,$up = true).'<div class="userfrnd">'.$message.'</div></li>';
            }
        }
        return $this->friend_username."$id|$messages|$randUser";
        // this is for ^^^^^^^ testing  purpose
    }
}
```

here is the other file where I am calling the other class method. And its `content-type` is `text/event-stream`

```
class update_chat extends SSEEvent {
    public function update(){
        //Here's the place to send data
        $feed = new Feed();
        return $feed->update_chat();
    }
    public function check(){
        //Here's the place to check when the data needs update
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any idea or suggestion why this problem persist ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you have any error?

Comment: no, thers is no error, its just returning empty string I think.

Comment: Is it possible that `$row["username"]` is empty?

Comment: no, `$row["username"]` is not empty, I  am also using that and its working good.

Comment: the `foo()` method is returning its all values where I am using it. but its not returning its value in `bar()` since I call `bar()` in another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are calling `bar()` in another file and then creating a new `Foo` in `otherClass`, you are not referencing the same instance of `Foo`. Either make `$friend_username` static and call it statically

```
public static $friend_username;

public function update(){
    //Here's the place to send data
    return Foo::$friend_username;
}
```

or at least make the function static

```
public static function bar() {}

public function update(){
    //Here's the place to send data
    return Foo::bar();
}
```

or pass in the instance of `Foo` to the function

```
public function update(Foo $Foo){
    //Here's the place to send data
    return $Foo->bar();
}
```

If you want to call a static method from within the same class, you have to use the [`self`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) identifier (`self::$var`)

```
    class Feed {
    public static $friend_username = array();

    // ONLINE FRIENDS LOGIC
    public function online_friends(){
        $friendsHTML = '';
        $countOnlineFriends = '';
        if(GetFriends($GLOBALS['log_username']) != false) {
            $all_friends = GetFriends($GLOBALS['log_username']);
            $orLogic = '';
            foreach($all_friends as $key => $user){
                if(IsBlocked($GLOBALS['log_username'],$user,true) == false){
                    $orLogic .= "username='$user' OR ";
                }
            }
            $orLogic = chop($orLogic, "OR ");
            $sql = "SELECT username, avatar, logged_in FROM users WHERE ($orLogic) AND logged_in = 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conx'], $sql);
            $friend_loggedIn = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                array_push(self::$friend_username, $row["username"]);
                $friend_avatar = $row["avatar"];
                $friend_loggedIn[] = $row["logged_in"];
                $friend_pic =  userImage(self::$friend_username,$friend_avatar,'42','42',$link = false,$up = true);
                $friendsHTML .= '<li><a href="#" onClick="chatbox(\''.self::$friend_username.'\',\''.getName(self::$friend_username,true).'\');return false;">'.$friend_pic.' '.getName(self::$friend_username,true).'</li>';
                $countFriends = count($friend_loggedIn);
                $countOnlineFriends = ($countFriends > 0) ? '<span class="online_friends animated">'.$countFriends.'</span>' : '';
            }
        }else{
            $friendsHTML = 'No friends';
        }
        return "$countOnlineFriends|$friendsHTML";
    }

    public function update_chat() {
        $id = '';
        $messages = '';
        $randUser = '';

        $user = Feed::$friend_username;
        foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
            $user[$key] = sanitize($value);
        }

        //I leave it up to you to figure out how you want to deal with the array of users in this next line
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_chat WHERE (sender='$GLOBALS[log_username]' AND receiver='$user') OR (sender='$user' AND receiver='$GLOBALS[log_username]') ORDER BY datetime DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conx'],$sql) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['db_conx']));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user1 = $row['sender'];
            $user2 = $row['receiver'];
            $message = parseData($row['message']);
            $did_read = $row['did_read'];
            $datetime = $row['datetime'];
            if ($user1 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $randUser = $user1;
            }elseif ($user2 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $randUser = $user2;
            }
            if ($user1 == $GLOBALS['log_username'] && $user2 != $GLOBALS['log_username']) {
                $messages .= '<li class="row" id="pm_row_'.$id.'"><div class="me">'.$message.'</div></li>';
            }else{
                $messages .= '<li class="row" id="pm_row_'.$id.'">'.userImage($randUser,getAvatar($randUser),28,28,$link = true,$up = true).'<div class="userfrnd">'.$message.'</div></li>';
            }
        }
        return Feed::$friend_username."$id|$messages|$randUser";
        // this is for ^^^^^^^ testing  purpose
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried that to make `$friend_username;` static. but that is same too.

Comment: I don't understand of this line `public function update(Foo $Foo)` how this works? as argument `Foo $Foo` ?

Comment: Type hinting http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php Technically you could get away without specifying that the argument should be of the class Foo, but it's better to have it in there.

Comment: you can see I only make 1 instance of this class 

`public function update(){
        //Here's the place to send data
        $Foo = new Foo();
        return $Foo->bar();
    }`

Comment: so it should return the bar() value

Comment: if you only have 1 instance of the class, then how are you calling `Foo::foo()` in another file?

Comment: I only make 1 instance in another file , and nowhere else.

Comment: Is that the file that holds `otherClass`? If not, then you seem to have two instances. I also updated my answer for how to properly call the static function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81588/discussion-between-brian-cohan-and-hsn0331).

Comment: when I use $self , should I declare `$friend_username` visibility to static?

Comment: `self::$friend_username` will only work if the variable is set to static. See the code above in my answer.

Comment: thats worked now :) but that is only returning the last element of that array :(

Comment: Well yeah, it's not an array. If you want to stash all of them, you need to set the value to an array and `use array_push()`

Comment: why the `$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db_conx'],$sql) or die(mysqli_error($GLOBALS['db_conx']));` is not executing in the `update_chat()`?

Comment: I see now `$user = sanitize(Feed::$friend_username);` has no empty value now, but the query is not executing

Comment: You'll have to loop `foreach (Feed::$friend_username as $key => $value) { Feed::$friend_username[$key] = sanitize($value); }`

Comment: please show me this example by updating in your answer

Comment: do I have to put all my code in foreach loop ? or how the `$user[$key] = sanitize($value);` works in the `$sql = "SELECT * FROM pm_chat WHERE (sender='$GLOBALS[log_username]' AND receiver='$user') OR (sender='$user' AND receiver='$GLOBALS[log_username]') ORDER BY datetime DESC";` ?

Comment: by using your new update, nothing happened like before. :(

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do. I suggest you read up on [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to see how that bit works. This discussion is also getting off topic as the original question was about passing values from one class to another. If you feel that you have that covered, I suggest you mark this as answered and open a new discussion on what your new issue is so that others who have the same issue as what you're now working on can see that rather than having it buried here.

Comment: your code is generating error `[26-Jun-2015 09:04:33 Asia/Karachi] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\xampp\htdocs\social_media\php_includes\classes\Feed.php on line 284`

Comment: thats right, but how it supposed to work your new code snippet?

Comment: my yes are too tired after a hard working and keep long vision on code. I am having problem to see and read code . :'(

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your are using the method *mysqli_fetch_array*, could it be that more than one element is returned and that the last one is empty?

BTW, I don't understand why you are making a single variable attribution inside a while statement. Supposedly, the last running (if some) will overwrite the variable's value.

Another observation, on the second code. If you are calling the **bar()** method right off the bat, shoudn't the variable be empty anyway? I understand that **$friend_username** is only assigned inside the **foo()** method.

Comment: no, that is not empty and not even the last element is empty.

Comment: and this is not single variable attribution in while, there is more. but I showed you in short to just demonstrate what is wrong with this. and what I am doing.

Comment: Alright. As I can only base myself for what I can see in your snippet of code,         $Foo = new Foo();
return $Foo->bar();
, it really seems to me that the $friend_username is not assigned at the moment. Could you show more of what is happening?